# R - Repeat Assignment for Each Character In Vector

Tags: r, loops, rvest

I have a vector with 30 characters:

```
tm <- c("CHI","CLE","IND","MIA","TOR","ATL","BOS","ORL","CHO","DET","NYK","WAS","MIL","BRK","PHI","GSW","SAS","OKC","DAL","MEM","LAC","UTA","HOU","MIN","POR","PHO","SAC","DEN","NOP","LAL")
```

I'm trying to create a new object for each of these characters.  The object is a list resulting from the **read_html** function below:

```
html_TOR <- read_html("http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/TOR/2016/gamelog/#tgl_advanced::none")
```

How can I create a loop that replaces "TOR" in the assigned object and URL within the function with each character in **tm** vector?

Here is my awful attempt... be kind.

```
for (i in tm) {html_[i] <- read_html("http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/[i]/2016/gamelog/#tgl_advanced::none")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your results in a list rather than separate objects and use create all the urls:

```
html <- list()
for (i in 1:length(tm)) {
    html[[i]] <- read_html(paste("http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/",tm[i],"/2016/gamelog/#tgl_advanced::none", sep="")
}
```

Comment: Thanks... this worked very well!  I will have to adjust my subsequent manipulation to work on the list now.